# UITapGestureReconizer error

Tags: xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I am getting errors with my UITapGestureReconizer like "UITapGestureReconizer undeclared". Because UITapGestureReconizer is inside a concrete class should it not be declared? and how do I fix it... below is where it first shows up in the code.

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    // set the tag for the image view
    [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

    // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [doubleTap release];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

        // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITapGestureRecognizer` is a part of UIKit, so it should be declared as long as you’re importing `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` somewhere. One problem I see in your code, though, is this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[doubleTap release];

…

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
```

At the point where you call `[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2]`, you don’t have a valid reference to `doubleTap`. It’s most likely retained by `imageView`, but that’s an implementation detail that you can’t rely on. Move the call to `-setNumberOfTapsRequired:` before the call to `-release` to ensure that this doesn’t break in a future version of iOS.